# Parse float to int in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've a set of data in a postgresql DB, where one of these columns store string data in float format, but now I need remove the decimal component of the string. How can I do this using an **sql update** statement in my BD console? Is that possible?

for example:

```
"25.3" -> "25"
```

If it does not possible how can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/how-can-i-convert-from-double-precision-to-bigint-with-postgresql

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You would be better suited casting the columns that were text, to numeric, to integer, so that rounding is taken into consideration e.g.

`SELECT '25.3'::numeric::integer AS num1, '25.5'::numeric::integer AS num2`

which would return integers of 25 and 26 respectively.

If you were not concerned with the digits following the point, the `floor(column_name::numeric)::integer` function or a substring, as mentioned, should be fine.

Comment: how can you keep `'25.5'::numeric::integer` as 25 ?

Comment: use the floor function `SELECT floor(25.5)::integer`

Answer (score -2):

Since it is a string, you can use string functions to drop the after decimal digits.
If you do not want to round them off, just drop the decimal part then use -

```
update table_name 
   set column_name = substring(column_name from 1 for position('.' in column_name)-1);
```

If you want rounding off, then you can use the cast as mentioned by @mlinth.

Comment: I solved my problem with the slow way, using like % operator, but i'll accept you answer, thanks